# Can we call graphic / web designers “typographers”?

Tags: website-design, typography, terminology

Since graphic or web designers focus on typography and different ways to treat the typeface, can we call them *typographers?*

Graphic and web designers spend significant time on choosing the typeface, pairing fonts, making text readable, legible and even more which comes under typography. Especially when dealing with text-heavy projects.

I’m talking about those who use appropriate typographic principles and treat the text in effective way in graphic and web designing.

According to my knowledge:
 **designing** the typeface is called **type design** and 
the art of **using** type is called as **typography**. 
I believe this is true and some people are confused with these two terms ([supporting link](http://johndberry.com/blog/2011/09/27/a-typographer-is-not-a-type-designer/)).

Comment: @bharat You can delete your own comments by hovering over them and clicking the ciruclar button with a cross that'll appear.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Very rarely.**

Any time you claim to be a professional X, you're staking your reputation on a claim to have **specific, comprehensive expertise** in that profession. With typography, some graphic designers can justify such a claim, but most can't stretch *that* far.

"Typographer" implies professional expert. Most good designers are *adept* at typography, and many be typography *enthusiasts*, but only a minority have gained that ***specific, comprehensive expertise***:

- **Expertise**: Could you do the things professional typographers do? Could you do it all day, every day? For example, imagine you work for a publishing house who are thinking of developing a new unique typeface for one of their publications, [like The Guardian did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardian_Egyptian) under designer/typographer/creative director [Mark Porter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Porter_(designer)). Could you:

  - research and make a coherent case for or against there being a business need for this from a typographic point of view?
  - identify what typographic properties and features the new typeface needs?
  - choose the most appropriate foundry and/or type designer, and explain clearly and coherently why?
  - oversee the typeface creation process, knowing when to demand, for example, higher or lower contrast or x-height (and why), which optional glyphs to include, what weights and variants, which languages to support?
  - produce or oversee the production of guidelines on correct usage of each variant?
- **Specific** expertise, deeper than that necessary for graphic design. You'd be expected to know the finer points of typography even if they don't often come up in the context of graphic design, from the advanced things OpenType is capable of to the difference between a "point" and a "[pica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pica_(typography))". No-one knows everything, but a "typographer" will love the opportunity to enthusiastically geek out about the fine detail side of typography even when they're not necessary for an active project. A few semi-random examples of topics I'd expect typographers to have opinions on but average designers to struggle with:

  - Appropriate uses of discretionary ligatures
  - The pros and cons of hinting
  - Typography trends such as foundaries like Tart Workshop who use high-tech OpenType features to simulate low-tech hand-lettering
  - Anything to do with the history of typography, movable type, letraset...
  - Typography in-jokes, like, what's the most embarassing [`keming`](http://www.ironicsans.com/2008/02/idea_a_new_typography_term.html) you've seen?
- **Comprehensive** expertise: Do you have the breadth of knowledge of a typographer, or do you only know those parts that touch on graphic design? Can you give genuine, informed, professional-level advice on, for example:

  - typography for paperback novels?
  - typography for low-quality paper?
  - typography for signage and wayfinding?
  - typography in cartography?
  - international typography and scripts? You don't need to be a linguist, but I would expect very basic passing awareness of what issues exists - for example, the importance of character encodings, or the fact that some scripts like Arabic are unreadable without correctly-applied ligature-like joins.

Most graphic designers (myself included) don't have this level of expertise, and can accurately describe themselves as designers and **typography enthusiasts** -  but to be a on a par with a professional typographer requires an extra level of expertise.

Some designers have this extra level, some are close or working towards it, but most don't.

Comment: That's fantastic answer @user568458 . I din't asked this question in order to claim myself as typographer. I do web designing, and I'm interested in typography too. I just want to know weather designers fall under typography, If not what differentiate them. You gave a perfect answer    explaining everything in detail! thumbs up! :)

Comment: I can't agree with this. Any decent graphic designer should have education, knowledge and experience in designing with type. That's not to say there aren't those that specialize in typography, who would likely have a high degree of expertise, but that doesn't--IMHO--exclude graphic designers from fitting into the typography bucket.

Comment: I certainly don't say graphic designers don't or can't be typographers (hence, "rarely"). For example, Mark Porter, the graphic designer turned creative director who led the redesign of The Guardian (including commissioning its new typefaces) is a great example of a designer who can *definitely* also be described as a great typographer. I'm just saying there's a gap between "designer and typography enthusiast" (most designers) and "designer and typographer" (some designers) - and it's depth and breadth of knowledge that bridges the gap.

Comment: Maybe "enthusiast" is the wrong word... Practitioner? Adept? "Journeyman but not master" is the sort of idea I'm getting at. Higher than "dabbler", lower than "professional expert". And I'm referring to average designers here - the ones who know their kerning from their leading but not much deeper.

Comment: As a one time professional typographer with a stupid amount of typographic knowledge in my head, I can tell you that the whole first section under "Specific" is superfluous. As far as understanding typography for various use cases, you don't need to know everything, and international (esp Arabic) is just academic unless you're actually designing for it. The "Real expertise" section is the heart of the matter. Those are the differentiating features.

Comment: @plainclothes thanks for the feedback! I did have that section first but for some reason moved it to the end... have put it first again, and I've edited to hopefully make it clearer that these are examples of having a knowledge and appreciation for the subject beyond what is necessary for active projects.

Comment: You have the essence of it, I just don't want any prospective typographers to get scared off and become Photoshop junkies instead ;-)

Comment: In my daily work I have to be wary of Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, Thai, Burmese, Devanagari, Japanese, Chinese and a smattering of other scripts - up to and including (last week) Egyptian Hieroglyphs. I regard myself as *technically* proficient, but indeed the last *total* redesign for the publishing house I do this for was supervised and veto'ed by an alumna of the Dutch KABK. The result was way better than I could have done on my own.

Comment: @Jongware having experts like you around makes multilingual type work a joy (◠‿◠)

Comment: @user568458 I guess what I'm getting at is that there shouldn't be a gap. It's like saying there's a gap between carpenters who are 'hammer enthusiasts' and carpenters that really know a hammer. Typography is a tool that every graphic designer should be adept at using, hence when they are using type, they are very much a typographer. I will concede that there will be different levels of expertise. Alas, 'typographer' does not, itself, come with any particular definition in terms of level of expertise other than 'competent'--IMHO.

Comment: @DA01 I don't agree with your analogy. There is a certain level of expertise required to give yourself the label of "typographer" — just having the basic expertise to set type properly, or to choose the right typeface for the job isn't enough. A better carpentry analogy: every carpenter worth their salt should be able to build a basic cabinet. But it takes a certain level of expertise to call yourself a cabinetmaker. There are certifications and [awards](http://www.istd.org.uk/awards) given for typography in Graphic Design, so certainly people have definitions.

Comment: @ghoppe that's fine that we don't agree. I think it really is an issue of semantics. To me, 'typographer' has no real hard definition in terms of skillset. I, personally, argue that if you are adept at designing with type, you're allowed to call yourself that. I appreciate that other's would disagree. Alas, there's no governing body for 'typography' to make the call :)

Comment: FYI, "cabinetmaker" is also not any sort of defined term in terms of skills beyond 'able to make furniture'. Any woodworker that has made furniture is, technically, a cabinetmaker. So that actually fits my analogy quite well :)

Comment: @DA01 Sorry, I can't agree. A web search will find apprenticeship programs for Cabinetmakers. I made a stool in high school shop, I wouldn't call myself a cabinetmaker nor a carpenter. Whether or not there are official "governing bodies" isn't that relevant. (Although actually there are trade associations for carpenters and graphic designers which are relevant and have accreditations to give.)

Comment: @DA01 We can both agree that there are skills required in order to work in typography and cabinetry. You seem to posit that there is no minimum level of skill required in order to call yourself either of those terms. This answer, and I, believe there is a minimum skill set required in order to honestly call yourself either of those terms.

Comment: @ghoppe it's relevant in that there's no governing body to say you *can't* call yourself a cabinetmaker. I agree that there *is* a minimum level of skill. What that is, however, is mostly going to be a matter of individual opinion (or, more precisely, the opinion of your customers).

Comment: @DA01 I also believe nothing says you *can't* call yourself a cabinetmaker. But if you are a carpenter who has only ever made one piece of furniture, it would be dishonest or disingenuous to do so.

Comment: @ghoppe you and I may agree on that, but my point is that it's merely our opinion. Maybe that person has a client that's really impressed with that one piece of furniture and is perfectly fine calling them a cabinetmaker.

Answer (score 6):

Your first line "Since graphic/web designers focus on typography" is by in itself not accurate. Graphic and web designers do a lot more than focus on typography. They are also responsible for layout design, they also plan and design interaction(web designers), they also plan and develop color themes. So in a nutshell, even if you spend a lot of time with typefaces, that just happens to be one function of being a graphic/web designer.

**Typographer**, on the other hand is a very specialized skill dealing mostly with typefaces. This [wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Typography) has good info.

HTH.

Comment: Yes, I agree that designers will do more than that. So according to you, though graphic and web designers perform typography, they are not called as typographer, right?

Comment: That is correct. Typography or a typographer is a specialized skill and not the same as being a graphic or web designer. And for clarity, they do not actually perform typography. They work with typefaces that are already available and to be used in their graphic or web projects.

Comment: You are telling that _typographers_ design the typeface. But what I tell is _typographers_  are those who use the typefaces in their design which are already created by _type designers_!  As you said "They (**designers**) work with typefaces that are already available...", that means they can be a typographer, right? Seems you are pointing typographer instead of type designer.

Comment: And from the wiki link you provided they mentioned something like this: *Typography* is performed by typesetters, compositors, typographers, graphic designers, art directors, manga artists, comic book artists, graffiti artists, clerical workers, and everyone else who arranges type for a product. It means designers can be a typographer, right?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say the other answers are wrong at all, but will simply offer a different POV:

> designing the typeface is called type design and
>
> the art of using type is called as typography

Those would also be my definitions. If you're skilled at designing with type, sure, you can call yourself a typographer. I'd argue any graphic designer or web designer of skill has typographic skills. Type is a basic building block of graphic designer.

There is no official test or anything like that. There's no governing body of typographers. For that matter, there's no official test or governing body for web designers or graphic designers.

This is really a question of semantics and, a such, will ultimately be very opinion based.